# Using app with AdMob as developer

Tags: android, admob

I have read the rules in the AdMob page and have tried to find an answer for this there. Couldn't find an answer there or somewhere to contact them so I'll try here.

It says the developer shouldn't inflate the earnings. Is this by clicking ads only or also by just loading an app.

Does it mean that as developer I can't use my own app, or just that I shouldn't press the ads?

Also, what is the purpose of having to give AdMob the deviceID? What is that used for? What would happen if you give it something similar instead (if it is just intrusive and doesn't serve a purpose)?

Comment: I think that the point it's not use or click, but dev must not abuse, like multiple fake click and more, on ads. I don't think that you can't open app, my app has ads (admob) and I don't nothing special

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use ur app as well as you also can tap on those ads,
Just impement a Method into AdRequest calls addtestdevice("DEVICEID")

Now Question is WHAT IS DEVICE ID, and How to get it,

Here is the Method to get DEVICE ID

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
String deviceId = md5(android_id).toUpperCase();
```

For e.g.

```
mAdRequest.addTestDevice(deviceId);
```

If You want to use it on Emulator the Emulator device id is TEST_EMULATOR

Hope it helps.

Cheers

-Aman